# Why state of reactjs doesn't work right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change the state by using a click. This is my code:

```
var List = React.createClass({

    getInitialState : function() {

      return {data : [], currentPage : 0} ;

    },
    componentDidMount : function() {
      this.getData() ;
    },
    getData : function() {
      console.log(this.state.cuurrentPage) ;
      //this is getting data from the server
    },
    incrementPage : function() {
      this.setState({currentPage : this.state.currentPage + 1}) ;
      this.getData() ;
    },
    return : function() {
     <button onClick={this.incrementPage}>More</button>
    }

})
```

but the changes happen only after the first click. After the first click I get the default state `"0"`, but when I do the second click I get changed state `"1"`.

Why is it works so? And how can change the state after the first click?

Comment: is it a typo:  `return: function()..` ?? It should be `render()`

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake when i was copying the code to here, but anyway this doesn't work as i want.

Comment: have you tried to run just  `console.log` in  `componentDidMount `.. Seams like its not called at all

Comment: Yes, componentDidMount works.

Comment: Please read the *big red box* in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate): *"`setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value."*.  The state gets updated just fine, but you are reading from the state *before* it was updated.

Comment: @ПавелКурбатский this means, you should access this.state in render ;) because render() is called every time the state changes.

Comment: Thank you guys, i'll read the documentation again.